# How can I acquire some ERC20 tokens to test AAVE on mumbai testnet?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, testnets, aave, polygon

I need to acquire some DAI or other assets which are supported by AAVE on Mumbai testnet to test my smart contract, but it seems that the AAVE faucet on their site is broken and does not work! (I wonder if anyone hasn't used it so far!) I reported this as a bug on their github, but still no reaction!
At first, I thought they might have published some publicly mintable tokens which I can mint by myself for testing purposes, but apparently, it is not the case. These are assets that I tested:

```
USDT: 0xBD21A10F619BE90d6066c941b04e340841F1F989
USDC: 0x2058A9D7613eEE744279e3856Ef0eAda5FCbaA7e
DAI: 0x001B3B4d0F3714Ca98ba10F6042DaEbF0B1B7b6F
```

However, I need some of those tokens and I want to know is there any way to get some?

Answer (score 1):

The best way i found was to use these resources:

https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/matic-polygon-market
This gets you the token addresses

https://explorer-mumbai.maticvigil.com/address/0x341d1f30e77D3FBfbD43D17183E2acb9dF25574E/write-contract
This allows you to write a contract to mint aave for example!

there are other ways you could create the contract to mint the tokens. You will spend MATIC for gas fees but its really not much.